# Edittext not show multiline

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a EditText and shows no multi line, not where I have the error, thank you for the interest shown. 
I like "edittext":

line 1 ==> s_p1

line 2 ==> s_p2

line 3 ==> s_postre

XML

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dip" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt_comida"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.15"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_comida" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_com"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.85"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:hint="@string/tv_com"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

CODE

```
String s_union = s_p1 + "\n" + s_p2 + "\n" + s_postre;
et_com.setText(s_union);
```

Comment: why EditText width is zero here?

Comment: Thank you for the response. This sera the mistake. He will verify it

Comment: android:layout_width="wrap_content". It gives the same mistake

Answer (score 0):

I didn't got what exactly you are trying to say.Do you want multiple lines in your Edit text?
 Then you add following line to your EditText.

```
     android:maxLines="any number"
```

Comment: I want to do is a vertically EditText with multiple lines. thanks for answering, now I test